A Jar must be built with JDK18 and must work on a computer with Java 1.8. Seems working, but how can I be SURE about its full compatibility with J1.8?
I downloaded and built the following jar:
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/tree/REL42.7.2
In particular, I ned the file postgresql.jar, and I must build by myself because I have to do a small change in its code (i cannot use the postgresql.jar as is provided from the official web page). I did succeed to make my change and to make it run on my application on a machine with Java 1.8.
But now, here is my doubt. In order to build the jar, I had to use Java 18, while Java 1.8 is installed on the computer where the application will run.
I cannot change the running Java on the machine where the jar will be loaded and used by my application. I cannot install Java 18 or a different Java than 1.8 on that computer.
Until now, the application seems working fine and connects with DB as expected. But I am afraid I will have some hidden problem. Why a jar that must be compiled with Java 18 is working with Java 1.8?
Maybe I should not worry, since no error is thrown, everything seems fine.
Anybody can give some info about?
Thank you.

UPDATE: the project is using kotlin (build.gradle.kts)

Why not use java 1.8 to compile your code?

“a jar that must be compiled with Java 18”? — What jar must be built with 18? The link you provide says that version of PostgreSQL JDBC Driver requires Java 8, not 18. Your Question is confused, voting to close.

“I have to do a small change.” —  Change what? The driver? An app calling the driver? Something else? What change, the source code, some configuration?

@Basil Bourque Question 1 when I try to build the project in IntelliJ, the build fails, unless I select JDK 18. Using JDK 1.8, or JDK 17, and even JDK21 I have on my computer generate a lot of errors; the build cannot even start, and gradle jobs are not seen by IntelliJ.
Question 2  I have to change the format some data are provided by the driver to my application. It is an old application and was working file only with old drivers. New ones need some manual changes on code. Anyway the important thing is I need to do a manual build compatible with Java 1.8

As long as your compiler is Java compliant your are ok.
Use target=1.8 and compiler will generate compatible bytecode.
EDIT
For gradle put
java.targetCompatibility = 1.8

into build.gradle.

can i add it in some gradle file? I am building in IntelliJ and gradle

Added config for gradle.

Thank you i think i solved in different way (see my answer), so i didn't test your solution and I didn't select as answer only because of that. I pushed it up as "useful answer" anyway

In my case i did the following:

unpacked the jar file (it's just a zipped file, as most of programmers know)
command

javap -verbose AnyFile.class 


the result was:

Classfile /C:/blablalba/AnyFile$1.class
  Last modified 1980-01-31; size 1398 bytes
  MD5 checksum .........
  Compiled from "AnyFile.java"
...
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52

So minor and major version are OK with Java 1.8, no matter which Java version was needed to build the jar. Seems the major version is more important, in this case, 52.

how does that answer the question "could be a problem in the future?" ?

"could be a problem in the future?" means that: during my test it seems working, but is it possible that, when the application will use all its features, one of such features will give an exception because it was compiled for a newer Java? - It seems not, since the result of the command clarifies that the bytecode is compatible with Java 1.8. I will try to change the question then to be more clear

I understood the question; what I have asked is how this post is answering that question?

@user85421 simply because the question is "how can I be SURE about its full compatibility with J1.8?" and here i have major and minor versions.

I know that it is very easy¹ to create a .class file with major version 52 (Java 8) but using a newer JRE library (e.g. JRE 11) and, consequently, using methods not available in Java 8 (e.g. String#repeat) - the class file can be executed, but obviously it will fail if that method is called || ¹ easy == by accident, like forgetting to also reset the JRE to version 8
